# Help on evaluating integral using partial fractions

Tags: integration

In Hydon's book "Symmetry methods for differential equations" in example 2.17. he mentions that
the following integral

$$ \int \frac{(x^3-x-3xy^2) dy + (y^3 +y -3x^2 y) dx}{(y^2 + x^2)(y^2 + (x+1)^2)(y^2+(x-1)^2)} = c $$

"is readily integrated (using partial fractions) to yield" the following result.

$$ \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{y}{x+1} \right) +  \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{y}{x-1} \right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x} \right) = c$$

I am not sure how to obtain this result. I am also not sure how to interpret the first integral in the first place. I think it is supposed to be line integral, but then how am I supposed to integrate that?

For example, when I tried decomposing the following into partial fractions, I found that no constants $A,B,C$ can be found to make the following equations satisfied.

$$\frac{1}{(y^2 + x^2)(y^2 + (x+1)^2)(y^2+(x-1)^2)} = \frac{A}{(y^2 + x^2)} + \frac{B}{(y^2 + (x+1)^2)} + \frac{C}{(y^2+(x-1)^2)}$$

$$\frac{x^2-1-3y^2}{(y^2 + x^2)(y^2 + (x+1)^2)(y^2+(x-1)^2)} = \frac{A}{(y^2 + x^2)} + \frac{B}{(y^2 + (x+1)^2)} + \frac{C}{(y^2+(x-1)^2)}$$

$$\frac{x^3-x-3xy^2}{(y^2 + x^2)(y^2 + (x+1)^2)(y^2+(x-1)^2)} = \frac{A}{(y^2 + x^2)} + \frac{B}{(y^2 + (x+1)^2)} + \frac{C}{(y^2+(x-1)^2)}$$

Which decomposition should I choose (so that it works)? I was motivated to take RHS of decompositions to be such that integrating will give $\tan^{-1}$, but that did not work.

Comment: What did you try? also, are you familiar with the gradient theorem?

Comment: My first thought: a backward approach with
$$
\tan^{-1}{(t)} = \int \frac{1}{1+t^2}\, dt
$$

Comment: @TomAriel Thanks for comment! I added what I tried with partial fractions. I am familiar with the gradient theorem but I am not sure how to use it in order to compute integral. Can you please give advice on that?

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks for comment! I tried going backwards and taking derivative of the final expression with $\tan^{-1}$s with respect to, say, $y$, but I got that it is equal to $0$ for all $x,y$. Do you know what does that mean? I can show calculations of that if you want

Comment: This is one of the many examples in higher mathematics where authors perform obscenely complex calculations, then claim the result is "readily obtained by..." or something of the same nature. But then even very good students have difficulty deriving the result. The author should have, at the very least, started calculating the integral so that a more curious student could check the result by themselves.